# All Pairwise Comparison between Rows and then Function between Columns

Tags: r

I have a large (20 000 rows, 200 columns) matrix in the following format:

```
mydata<-matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=8,nrow=4)
```

I am looking to first subtract each row from from all other rows and then on each new row perform a t.test returning the p.value comparing columns 1:4 and columns 5:8.

This would return something similar to:

```
Row1 Row2 0.03
Row1 Row3 0.66
Row1 Row4 0.001
```

I have written a sample that accomplishes this with a for loop for clearer understanding (albeit slightly different output), however it is obviously not efficient enough to handle such a large dataset.

```
sigdiff<-matrix(, nrow = nrow(mydata), ncol = nrow(mydata))
for (i in 1:(nrow(mydata)-1)){
for (k in (i+1):(nrow(mydata)-1)){
diff<-mydata[i,]-mydata[k,]
sigdiff[i,k]<-t.test(diff[1:4],diff[5:8])$p.value
}
}
sigdiff[is.na(sigdiff)]=1
```

Thanks for your help in optimizing this!

Comment: That's entirely too large an example data set.  Can you please reduce its size.  We'll only need a small set to solve the big issue.

Comment: I edited it with a smaller example

Comment: The return you ask for is (about) `(2e5)^2`, or 40 billion lines long. What are you going to do with the results? Do you really need to keep all of them, or only the ones where the p.value is below some threshold? If you care about the distribution, would a "small" sample of only a few million be enough?

Comment: For sure - I do not need all of that. Maybe we could start with the smallest 100 p values and then move up from there if we can get it working. As well, I thought it should only be (2e4)^2, or 400 million

Comment: Whoops, read it as 200 000. Right you are.